# vtiger 7.1 installation error Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am facing an issue in vtiger 7.1 installation
insted of setup page , it shows error page with this content

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; RecurringType has a deprecated constructor in /home/domainname/domains/domainfolder/public_html/vtigercrm/include/utils/RecurringType.php on line 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error is generating because of invalid "error_reporting" variable in php.ini

as you may know , the required value of error_reporting for installing vtigercrm is "E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT"

so if current value is E_All or something else , In php.ini set "error_reporting" as below

error_reporting = E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in config.inc.php

```
ini_set('display_errors','on'); error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

Or turn off error reporting:

```
error_reporting(0);
```