# vtiger php errors on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am getting a tons of warnings in vtiger on php7.0 on ubuntu 16.04

I was thinking to disable the warnings via /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini , but it does not make any difference

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_USER_WARNING & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

here the errors which I still get:

```
Warning: Declaration of Portal_Module_Model::saveRecord($recordId, $bookmarkName, $bookmarkUrl) should be compatible with Vtiger_Module_Model::saveRecord(Vtiger_Record_Model $recordModel) in /var/www/vtigercrm/modules/Portal/models/Module.php on line 0

Warning: Declaration of Portal_Module_Model::deleteRecord($recordId) should be compatible with Vtiger_Module_Model::deleteRecord(Vtiger_Record_Model $recordModel) in /var/www/vtigercrm/modules/Portal/models/Module.php on line 0

Warning: Declaration of EmailTemplates_Module_Model::saveRecord(EmailTemplates_Record_Model $recordModel) should be compatible with Vtiger_Module_Model::saveRecord(Vtiger_Record_Model $recordModel) in /var/www/vtigercrm/modules/EmailTemplates/models/Module.php on line 0

Warning: Declaration of EmailTemplates_Module_Model::deleteRecord(EmailTemplates_Record_Model $recordModel) should be compatible with Vtiger_Module_Model::deleteRecord(Vtiger_Record_Model $recordModel) in /var/www/vtigercrm/modules/EmailTemplates/models/Module.php on line 0
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is this from the vtiger code itself?  If so have you checked for updates/compatibility on their web site.  As for disabling the errors - that's not a good idea as it just hides problems which will come back and bite you later (no pun about tigers meant).

Answer (score 1):

Change error reporting in config.inc.php file

```
ini_set('display_errors','on'); version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) : error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);   // DEBUGGI
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify error_reporting via config.inc.php
please check the following link.

[vtiger 7.1 installation error Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034151/vtiger-7-1-installation-error-deprecated-methods-with-the-same-name-as-their-cl/54261343#54261343)